# Retrieving users in a certain role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Recently, I have come upon an issue that I've been trying to solve, yet I haven't been able to find a good solution or make one.
My goal was to check a role and see how many users it has that are online. So far, it checks every 1 hour and I have made it so that it starts once the bot is ready (through the `ready` event).
The issue that I've been having is actually retrieving the list of people that are online in a certain role, and I'm not sure how to proceed. I currently have this code (it's very simple and doesn't include much) and I'm not too sure what to do in order to make the bot check for members in the specified role and check their status, to make sure they are online or not.

If anyone can provide any help or lead me in the correct direction, that would be great. Thank you. (Additionally, it is very basic code currently that does absolutely nothing, it's just what I'm starting with. I'm not sure how to find the rest, I have already tried going through the documentation but I wasn't able to find what I needed.)

```
function showOnline() {
  let onlinePeople;

  let onlineEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
    .setColor("#00ff00")
    .setDescription(`${onlinePeople}`)
    .setFooter();
}

setInterval(showPeople, 2000); // 3600000 (1 hour)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`<Role>.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=members) returns a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)s. The GuildMember class has a [`presence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=presence) property, which returns a [Presence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence). The Presence class has a [`status`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=status) property, which returns a string that is either "online"/"offline"/"idle"/"dnd".

So, using these properties and by utilising the [`filter`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) method for a Collection, you can *filter* a *collection* of *members* from a *role*, where the *guildmember*'s *presence* has the *"online"* status.

This results to: `<Role>.members.filter(member => member.presence.status === "online")`, which returns a Collection of GuildMembers that have a certain role and are online at the time.

Then, you can use something like [`<Collection>.map()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) to get the property you want from the collection, for example if you wanted the usernames from the GuildMembers you can do `<Collection of GuildMembers>.map(member => member.user.username)` which will return an array of usernames from the collection of members.

Comment: Thank you for the response! If I may ask, what would <Role> be in this case? Would I need to get the ID of the role and then use "find" for roles?

Comment: You can do either, `<Guild>.roles.find(role => role.name === "name of the role")` or `<Guild>.roles.get(id)`. Both would return a <Role> object.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'll try this out :)

Comment: Thank you. It all worked out. Additionally, for the mapping, you'd want to have it as `<Collection of GuildMembers>.map(member => member.user.username)`